# Win EC7 licenses: what does "depending on device type" mean?

Tags: windows-ce, windows-embedded-compact

using the 'runtime license assessment tool' for the first time in Embedded Compact 7, I'm a bit puzzled about it's output.
My questions are:

- why is e.g. the SIP listed in two different licenses (C7E and C7P)?
- what does 'depending on device type' mean?

As I didn't find any useful information on MSDN, I would be glad for any help.
Thanks in advance.

Regards, Timm.

**Excerpt from the runtime license assessment tool report:**

**Windows Embedded Compact 7.0 C7E Run-Time License**

SIP for Large Screens  SYSGEN_LARGEKB

SIP for Small Screens  SYSGEN_MSIM

**Windows Embedded Compact 7.0 C7G or C7P Run-Time License depending on device type.**

SIP for Large Screens  SYSGEN_LARGEKB

SIP for Small Screens  SYSGEN_MSIM

**Windows Embedded Compact 7.0 C7P Run-Time License**

SIP for Large Screens  SYSGEN_LARGEKB

SIP for Small Screens  SYSGEN_MSIM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to our distributor, the software input panel is included in both, C7P and C7E licenses. Only the display of the platform builder license assessment tool is wrong.

As for 'depending on device type', there's serveral types of devices (navigation, set top..) which grant special licenses.